# Decent (r-tree, quad-tree or similar) library in ruby for searching spatial data

Tags: ruby, quadtree, r-tree

I have a database of 20k+ cities with latitude and longitude and I need to make lot of nearest point queries (*which city is the nearest to certain lat,long point*) against this dataset.

I guess an R-Tree or QuadTree would be a perfect data structure for this, but I haven't been able to find a working ruby implementation. Do you know any?

Answer (score 3):

I've found the [kd-tree](http://gurge.com/blog/2009/10/22/ruby-nearest-neighbor-fast-kdtree-gem/) gem which helped me solve the above task

Answer (score 2):

Or try:

https://github.com/iterationlabs/rquad